# Resizing Panels in proportion to form

Tags: forms, delphi, resize, panel, proportions

[image]

I am developing a Delphi game for my (grade 10) PAT.

I am using an image as a grid for my game and placing individual panels in each grid because I do not know how to use string grids as it's my first year with Delphi. When I place the panels perfectly in each grid of the image and run my code everything looks normal until I go full screen,then all the panels are in each grid but the size is not in proportion with the image as I placed it before.
A solution would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Look at the properties "Align" and "Anchor" to make the components auto-size and/or auto-move when you resize the form... If these aren't enough, you'll have to place some manual resizing code in the OnResize event...

Comment: I've tried changing this before and it didnt work.

Comment: I cant figure out what code to write to manually resize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TGridPanel` in place of your image.  Each panel goes into one cell of the grid, and with the column widths and row heights set as a percentage (which is the default), and both the grid and the panels in the grid having `Align` set to `alClient`, the cells, and therefore the panels, will adjust their size proportional to the entire form.

Comment: Thank you so much i tried using a TGridPanel but was unsure what it was or does.